# What is really necessary for importing MongoDB in Gradle/Intellij?

Tags: java, mongodb, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

I'm building a java application with Intellij-idea, Gradle and Mongo. I created a new Gradle project and  I was having some trouble importing `mongodb-java-driver` inside my project. I modified this piece of code inside `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
 testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
 compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.4.1'
}
```

But was unable to use Mongo with Java. My `External Libraries` didn't have any Mongo jar. Then I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40431480/gradle-java-and-mongodb) that I should add the `application` plugin to my `build.gradle`. I searched on the [official docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) that this plugin *"will automatically add run task that will execute the specified main class with all the runtime dependencies automatically put on the classpath:"* as the answer linked above stated. But this didn't solved my problem.

Then I added the `idea` plugin, since I saw [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html) that *"The IDEA plugin generates files that are used by IntelliJ IDEA, thus making it possible to open the project from IDEA"*. I didn't think that would help me but was worth a try. Unfortunately, this didn't helped either.

After this I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31195053/3026886) that I should synchronize my project. Since I created this from zero and didn't import any complete project from outside I didn't understand why I should synchronize it. While it was synchronized, I saw Intellij was downloading `mongo-java-driver`. After that, I still was unable to use Mongo. I had to add  the downloaded jar to my project class path, as this was one of the suggested corrections given by Intellij.

I've come from Eclipse/Maven and I'm discovering how Intellij/Gradle behave. So my question is what is strictly necessary to use `mongodb-java-driver` on Intellij/Gradle and why I had to synchronize my project? Is this the correct way of using Gradle? Always building and synchronizing after?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Mongo is a DB. What do you mean when you say you want to use Mongo in your java?

Comment: I'm trying to correctly set up a simple application that uses Mongo as DB as this [tutorial for Eclipse/Maven](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-hello-world-example/)

Comment: And what does it mean when you say "I was unable yo use Mongo with Java"? Can I assume you mean that the code form the tutorial didn't compile? Or it compiled but didn't work?

Comment: The code didn't compile because Intellij was unable to find any mongo classes

Comment: `Gradle` can auto import libraries in intellij go to File->Settings->Build->Gradle->use auto-import. Otherwise, you need manually import the libraries on your own (through the synchronize button) the pulgins you mentioned are not related to this subject

Comment: But importing the library was only available after I synchronized my project. I would like to discover the purpose or correct way of always synchronizing after adding a new dependency

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133227/discussion-between-guy-grin-and-gabrielrado).